# JQuery toggle doesn't show up when Page Loads up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, toggle

I've UI issue to show "ShowLink". It fades out when Page Loads up. Logically it should fade out when user clicks ShowLink. Can anyone help me to fix the bug in the code ?

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="number" runat="server" />
            <div>
                <a id="A1" href="#">Show Details</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="question" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

            <div id="Div1">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showLink').toggle(function () {
            $('#questionDetails').load('/Reviews/Sub/ViewQuestion.aspx?id=<%= pageId %> #questionContainer');
            $('#questionDetails').fadeIn();
            $(this).text("Hide Detail...");
        },
    function () {
        $('#questionDetails').fadeOut();
        $(this).text("Show Detail...");
    }
    );
        var nmbr = $(".number");
        nmbr.parent().width(nmbr.width() + 50);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've found a solution. Issue is not with Code, Code is absolutely fine. Issue is with JQuery Version that were used in the code is outdated and toggle doesn'
t work currently with same version now. 
Solution: We may resolve this issue following other way, I tried to avoid using toggle and worked find.Simply just add a if -else on click based upon id or text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code inside the #showLink click event,

```
$('#showLink').click(function () {
        $('#questionDetails').load('/Reviews/Sub/ViewQuestion.aspx?id=<%= pageId %> #questionContainer');
        $('#questionDetails').fadeIn();
        $(this).text("Hide Detail...");
    },
function () {
    $('#questionDetails').fadeOut();
    $(this).text("Show Detail...");
}
);
    var nmbr = $(".number");
    nmbr.parent().width(nmbr.width() + 50);
});
```